# Using unit method

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I have following definition and implementation:

```
case class State[S, +A](run: S => (A, S)) {
  def map[B](f: A => B): State[S, B] =
    flatMap(a => unit(f(a)))

  def map2[B, C](sb: State[S, B])(f: (A, B) => C): State[S, C] =
    flatMap(a => sb.map(b => f(a, b)))

  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = State(s => {
    val (a, s1) = run(s)
    f(a).run(s1)
  })
}

object State {

  def unit[S, A](a: A): State[S, A] =
    State(s => (a, s))

  def get[S]: State[S, S] = State(s => (s, s))

}

trait RNG {
  def nextInt: (Int, RNG) // Should generate a random `Int`. We'll later define other functions in terms of `nextInt`.
}

object RNG {

  // NB - this was called SimpleRNG in the book text

  case class Simple(seed: Long) extends RNG {
    def nextInt: (Int, RNG) = {
      val newSeed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL // `&` is bitwise AND. We use the current seed to generate a new seed.
      val nextRNG = Simple(newSeed) // The next state, which is an `RNG` instance created from the new seed.
      val n = (newSeed >>> 16).toInt // `>>>` is right binary shift with zero fill. The value `n` is our new pseudo-random integer.
      (n, nextRNG) // The return value is a tuple containing both a pseudo-random integer and the next `RNG` state.
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how to use the `unit` function on `State` object? I've try as follow:

```
val s2 = State.unit[RNG, Int](4563)
println(s2.run((x: RNG) => x))
```

But the compiler complains:

```
Error:(12, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : state.RNG => state.RNG
 required: state.RNG
    println(s2.run((x: RNG) => x)._1)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compilation error is due to your invocation of `s2.run`. `run` is a function with type `S => (A, S)`, so given a value of the state type it returns a pair containing the result and the new state. Since `s2` has type `State[RNG, Int]`, `s2.run` has type `RNG => (Int, RNG)` so you need to provide a value of `RNG`, for example:

```
s2.run(new RNG.Simple(1))
```

you are providing a function `RNG => RNG`.

Comment: `run`expects a function and return a tuple `case class State[S, +A](run: S => (A, S))`, why do I have to pass the instance of `RNG.Simple`?

Comment: @zero_coding - `run` is a function from the state type to a pair of `(result type, state type)` so you need to provide it with a value of the state type. `s2` has type `State[RNG, Int]` so `s2.run` has type `RNG => (Int, RNG)`.